# Can a question have both c# and vb.net tags when relevant to both?

Tags: discussion

I recently found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551861) which originally had both `c#` and `vb.net` tags. The question was about how to sort a ListBox, which is relevant to both languages. I decided to answer it in vb.net. Later, the vb.net tag was removed and my answer downvoted because it was the wrong language. Fine. I added c# to my answer. People seemed unhappy that the vb.net was still there.

In my opinion, this question is about `.NET` and `winforms`, and could be relevant to either c# or vb.net. Just Google this: `How to sort items in listbox vb.net` and you should see the question. So if a vb.net dev is looking for an answer to the question, they could stumble upon mine, and would get a solution. If this is the case, then what is the harm in leaving the tag? I would argue that it is in fact more beneficial than detrimental to include the vb.net tag.

Comment: For a question to which the reader of the question really doesn't care which language an answer uses, using both can be appropriate.  When the reader is going to be expecting a particular language then no, the question shouldn't be tagged with both languages

Comment: That's assuming the question is only meant to help the OP. This would effectively make the question less useful to the community as a whole.

Comment: I never used the term OP in my comment, and that was very intentional.

Comment: I should have read your comment better. Then it's a chicken and egg thing. Without the `vb.net` tag, vb.net readers would land there less, and there would be no point for supplying the solution in vb.net. Including the tag would attract more vb.net readers, and it would make sense to include that solution.

Comment: It's not a question of *how many* readers are expecting VB in the answers, it's whether the person seeking the answer is expecting *an* answer in VB or if the person seeking an answer to the question *really doesn't care if they get an answer in VB or C#*.  If the question and answer are written such that the people finding the question won't *care* which language is used (this is often that case if the question is a higher level question in which the code itself is more tangential, and it is the English Explanations that matter) then using both is appropriate.

Comment: You're basically just proposing that people ask two separate questions, asking for a VB and a C# solution, in one question.  SO is designed to have one question per question.  If you want to know how to solve a problem in both C# and VB, then you have two questions, not one.

Comment: I see your point, and think you're right, it should be two questions. Part of my position on this came from me being a vb.net dev and having to google "how to ... c#" to get a quality answer out of SO because of c#'s popularity compared to vb.net. My idea was that it *wouldn't hurt* to supply both when the question is relevant to both. However, SO is not set up this way.

Comment: [Relevant.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194013/144883).  Probably best to choose C# next time, you'll get hassled less.

Comment: Sigh... yes I have become more fluent in `C#` by searching for solutions to `.NET` problems which have no answer `in VB.NET` on SO. I guess I should see this as a good thing. Conform!

Comment: Dear God, all the backticks.

Comment: No matter how difficult it is for you to look at, i assure you it was harder for me to type them all.

Comment: @HansPassant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573224/telerik-handle-the-clicking-on-raddropdownbutton-text-zone @ DJKRAZE's comments to the question. They have been removed...

Answer (score 3):

You're basically just proposing that people ask two separate questions, asking for a VB and a C# solution, in one question. SO is designed to have one question per question. If you want to know how to solve a problem in both C# and VB, then you have two questions, not one.

There are circumstances where it's appropriate for a question to be tagged with those languages, but that is when reader of the question *won't care which language is used*. (This is often that case if the question is a higher level question in which the code itself is more tangential, and it is the English Explanations that matter.)  If readers of a particular question are going to want the question/answer to be in a particular language, then the question should be specific to that language instead of trying to smush two separate questions into one space.

Answer (score 1):

You can prioritize tag over the other by what the OP's prioritized. He posted code in `C#`, then he seem to rather see code in `C#` than `VB`. But if no sign of any of those languages, you can just tag it as `.NET`.

Google won't benefit from adding `VB.NET` or `C#` to the search bar, he won't associate title with tags. (From my experience)

I don't think you can force everyone to write multiply solutions, even after you can, you can't because you have more than 10 .NET programming languages ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages)) and you can't make them all know those languages, but you can't just prioritize few languages.

To solve this, download C#2VB tool and use it.

Comment: This is a concise answer, makes sense. Code was supplied in c#. But when the question could apply to either language, regardless of code supplied, *what is the harm* in answering with both c# and vb.net?

Comment: @DanVerdolino I wrote about it too, you can just tag it as `.NET`.

Comment: @DanVerdolino The harm is noise.  SO is all about having a high signal to noise ratio.  When anyone reading the question is forced to ignore half of every answer, that's a problem.

Comment: @DanVerdolino About the harm thing is, that there's a lot more .NET languages that it won't fit into the tags' bar. Why choose VB.NET over others?

Comment: @Servy I don't think it's noise if it's somehow helpful to others, even if a bit. But that's almost an opinion.

Comment: @KugBuBu Yes, it is.  I didn't say that all VB code would inherently be useless.  A question with both solutions is half noise because no matter what, the reader is forced to ignore half of the answer.  It doesn't matter which half they need to ignore, there's still half of it that they need to sift through.  The whole point of having a high signal to noise ratio is that when someone has a problem and they are looking for a solution, whenever they see something that helps them solve their problem its signal, when they see something that doesn't it's noise.

Comment: @Servy in the case of the question `How to sort items in listbox` a vb dev would either see 0:1 or 1:1 SNR. The c# dev would see 1:0 or 1:1 SNR. The OP's code has nothing to do with this. Saying we should defer to the OP's code for the answer's language selection seems arbitrary unless the sole reason is to reduce the c# dev's SNR.

Comment: @Servy I read it wrong. I thought it was the same as adding `VB` and `C#` as tags. I think it's more of a problem because it isn't associated with the OP's question. If VB programmer want to understand the C# code, he can just paste the code to some C#2VB tool. But still it will be good feature to have tabbed code panel, but I don't think you can force everyone to learn VB or use a tool to use this feature.

Comment: @DanVerdolino If VB devs are looking for solutions to this problem then a VB question can be asked and answered, giving programmers in both languages a 1:1 SNR, rather than giving everything a 1:2 SNR.  If you have two separate questions then *ask two separate questions*.  I didn't say, "ask one question and refuse to let people ask the other question."