# Are the only tags allowed those that the author "could have intended"?

Tags: discussion

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35631719/1766265) a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638278/detect-whether-text-is-bold-italic) which was written when Objective-C was the only way to make iOS apps. The answer uses Swift.

I received a down vote, because

> "Swift answer for 4 year old question tagged Obj-C."

I then added the `swift` tag to the question but it was removed by the person who downvoted with the reason:

> "There is no way the author could've meant to ask for swift, so your edit clearly conflicts with the author's intend. [...]"

My question is NOT about wether or not this specific tag belongs to this specific question, but in general, is it bad practise to change tags based on the evolution of the Q&A as a whole?

Comment: you shouldn't change the intent of a post with an edit. Adding swift to make your answer "valid".... is pretty much exactly that

Comment: In general, you can always write and self-answer your own question if you feel your answer has value (and the question hasn't already been asked).  I remember there was a meta question about Swift and Objective-C questions specifically, though I don't remember what it concluded.

Comment: Possibly related: [Is it acceptable to post answers in Swift on iOS/OS X questions marked with the Objective-C tag and vice versa?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285258/is-it-acceptable-to-post-answers-in-swift-on-ios-os-x-questions-marked-with-the)

Comment: What I want to know: how did *three* editors editing the tags manage not to remove the incorrect [tag:bold]???

Comment: Retagging question and changing its context is just the start of a huge problem with legacy content. It makes the other answers seem irrelevant and eventually users will downvote them as well. (so many stupid people not answering *the* question! that will teach them..)

Comment: Certainly not. The author isn't infallible about what's relevant. Very often author tags have to be removed and others provided. And as per your example, relevancy can change over time.

Answer (score 53):

Rules that require reading someone's mind are not good rules.

Rules that prevent us from improving the site in deference to someone who got his question answered 4+ years ago are also not particularly good rules.

Fortunately, there are no rules that say you can't edit tags if the author wouldn't have added them. Can you imagine if we did? All MySQL questions on Stack Overflow would be tagged [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php). Tags should always describe the content of the question, and if the author's own tags don't do that then it's our *duty* to change them.

So let's look at your specific case:

- The question isn't about Objective-C; it's about the iOS API, with [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) added because it's traditional on Stack Overflow to use language tags in sort of a meta sense to request that answers be provided in that language. Since no other languages were encouraged for iOS development back in 2011, *of course* it would be this one.
- The same guy who removed your [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag also removed the [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) tag and *added* the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag. Now, it's a pretty good bet the asker *was* actually developing software for the iPhone, so we can dismiss any notions of sacrosanct author intentions right now: ios makes a better tag, and as your adversarial editor realizes, better tagging trumps speculation on author intent any day.

So hopefully, we've put this whole "author intent" thing to rest. We're just left with the question of whether it's appropriate to answer an *API* question, with a preferred language specified, in an alternate language.

This has been somewhat controversial for years, even on platforms whose owners *weren't* keeping a choke-hold on the practical availability of languages. I'd imagine that on iOS, a platform only recently blessed with a *second* supported language, the bright light of *choice* might be unbearably blinding for some.

So... That's the environment you have to navigate. If more people are offended by seeing a Swift answer than are aided by it, your answer will end up with a negative score. If it turns out Swift coders need to detect bold text too, then you might end up with a positive one. Make the call based on your perception of need, not anyone else's. Or [as Anthony Pegram wrote years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93747/warning-message-for-vb-net-questions-being-answered-with-c-solution/93748#93748),

> Expanding outwards to cover the non-.NET universe, if the answer is indeed in the wrong language and it does not assist in answering the question, that's where we have downvotes. But if the answer helps move the needle, then the language itself is not a problem. It could even be pseudocode, for all we care.

Truth be told, that question doesn't really need *either* language tag at this point; the question isn't about Swift but isn't any more about Objective-C; if I was searching for an answer to this problem on *any of the other platforms* where Objective-C can be used, I'd be mighty irritated that this question pops up; frankly, [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) would make a better tag than [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) at this point.

### Related:

- [People changing other people's tags to make it wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34123/people-changing-other-peoples-tags-to-make-it-wrong)
- [Warning message for VB.NET questions being answered with C# solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93747/warning-message-for-vb-net-questions-being-answered-with-c-solution)
- [Is it OK to use language-specific tags for problems with that are not directly connected to coding in such language?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298019/is-it-ok-to-use-language-specific-tags-for-problems-with-that-are-not-directly-c?rq=1)
- [Can a question have both c# and vb.net tags when relevant to both?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270101/can-a-question-have-both-c-and-vb-net-tags-when-relevant-to-both)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this post to my attention. Please note that the "iphone" tag is intended to be used with hardware-specific questions, which isn't the case here; if this wasn't tagged objective-c by the author, I'd never even criticized the answer, nor downvoted. Please also note that as time of that post, many other languages including Haskell and C have been perfectly okay to develop iOS apps in.

Comment: I'm familiar with [the history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317603/tags-ios-iphone-cocoa-touch-objective-c-etc/317605#317605) there, @Jan - note though that when the question being discussed was asked, the rebrand had been in place for barely a year and the iphone tag was still something like 5x more popular on Stack Overflow for these questions. Situations change; tags should change with them.

Comment: Right; that's for the iphone/ios retag. Now running around and doing the (trivial) translation of objective-c code to swift on old questions is something I prefer to use downvoting for when I stumble over it. **Adding** the swift tag to make this right should never have gotten reviewed as the other answer already points out and I did in a comment on the answer in question.

Comment: I agree, but not because of any nonsense about author intent - it's just an unnecessary tag. You could've dropped [objective-c] while you were editing too. As for downvoting... That's your prerogative; as I said in my answer here, ultimately the votes from all readers will determine the worth of an answer, regardless of language.

Comment: Exactly:) as for objc, as in that time the haskell iOS build chain came along, I rather didn't want to guess, even if chances are objc might be a mistag as well.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I knew a guy who used to throw [tag:logo] on questions, because... Hey, it *could* be correct.

Comment: @JanGreve Forgive me for getting one-to-one here, but if you "prefer to use downvoting" because you feel I'm "running around and doing the (trivial) translation of objective-c code to swift on old questions", than that's perhaps a bit prejudiced. I saw the WWDC 2015 video about Swift 2.0 and found this new way of achieving it much more readable, concise than any Swift or Obj-C way before this and therefore a valid answer to the question. I do hope you reconsider this way of looking at Swift answers on Obj-C posts.

Comment: There are some good points in here, but it seems to look more at whether it's okay to answer an old question asked in LanguageA later on with a response in LanguageB, when what we're really looking at is if it's also okay to then edit the question to add the additional language tag. While I agree 100% it's fine to answer the question, I'm not so sure adding the language tag is such good practice. Sure, let's add an `ios-api` tag (or similar), but the `swift` tag seems like it's putting a whole new dimension into the question that wasn't there before.

Comment: To continue, I'm not 100% against the idea, either. If I'm a swift developer looking for help, having that tag there is a definite win. Maybe I should search for `ios` instead, but that doesn't always happen. And for this reason I also would never want to remove the `objective-c` tag, which was part of the suggestion. Back to the swift tag, though, adding it is only an improvement if the answer is quality. Older questions tend to attract many fewer views/votes, and so the answer published along with the new tag has limited opportunity for review compared to a new question in the same area.

Comment: I think the tagging is mostly a red herring here, @Joel; the question was whether it's ok to add tags that "the author didn't intend" - but we do that all the time, because it's not always obvious to askers which tags are appropriate. So that's a really boring question. A slightly more interesting question is whether language tags should be added to language-agnostic API questions; as you note, there's a SEO justification for that, but if we're after SEO then [tag:iphone] beats all. The truth though, is this specific argument (and many like it) don't start with tagging; they're language wars.

Comment: So many new insights. A special thanks to @Shog9 for taking the time to elaborate so much on the issue.

Comment: But... What if I'm developing for iPad?

Answer (score 1):

As the help-center says:

> #### When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks

Your edit clearly doesn't follow that mandate.
The rejection-reason for any such edit-suggestion is:

> #### clearly conflicts with author's intent
>
> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Or (as it was only a tag-edit), the one which nearly got your edit rejected as it should have been:

> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.

If you have a good answer, but no question to go with it, you might be able to write an acceptable on-topic question for it. Just don't try to take over some different question which is nearly what you want to answer. Self-answers are allowed, even encouraged.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly my thinking on this.

Comment: @JanGreve tell that to everyone editing [tag:swift] onto old iOS questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/901357/6).  Fortunately, the edit was reversed here, but that hasn't stopped people in the past.

Comment: *to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages*.  That seems to me to be entirely in keeping with the edit proposed.

Comment: How can you say "Your edit clearly doesn't follow that mandate"??  Are you asserting that the editor did not feel they could make the post better, or were not inclined to do so?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: It's "without changing it" that was tripped on.

Comment: You're quoting the letter of the law, while its spirit is somewhere entirely else.